# Разница между display: inline-table; и display: block;

Tags: css, html5, display

Вопрос:

какая разница между `display: inline-table;` и `display: block;` или вобще

> отсутствии display

в **CSS** в элементе UL в контексте HTML5? Т.е. в горизонтальном меню

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Photoshop</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Illustrator</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Web Design</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Articles</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">User Experience</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Inspiration</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

и

```
nav {
    margin: 0px; 
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}

nav ul ul {
    display: none;
}

    nav ul li:hover > ul {
        display: block;
    }


nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin: 0px; 
    padding: 0px;
}
    nav ul:after {
        content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
    }

    nav ul li {
        float: left;
    }
        nav ul li:hover {
            background: #4b545f;
        }
            nav ul li:hover a {
                color: #fff;
            }

        nav ul li a {
            display: block; padding: 25px 40px;
            color: #757575; text-decoration: none;
        }


    nav ul ul {
        background: #5f6975; border-radius: 0px; padding: 0;
        position: absolute; top: 100%;
    }
        nav ul ul li {
            float: none; 
            border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a; position: relative;
        }
            nav ul ul li a {
                padding: 15px 40px;
                color: #fff;
            }   
                nav ul ul li a:hover {
                    background: #4b545f;
                }

    nav ul ul ul {
        position: absolute; left: 100%; top:0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При отсутсвтии display у каждого элемента имеется свое изначальное состояние display.

• ***inline-table*** - Определяет, что элемент является таблицей как при использовании тега , но при этом таблица является встроенным элементом и происходит ее обтекание другими элементами, например, текстом.

• ***block*** - Элемент показывается как блочный. Применение этого значения для встроенных элементов, например тега , заставляет его вести подобно блокам — происходит перенос строк в начале и в конце содержимого.

**Основное отличие:** inline-table - не занимает всю ширину определенного блока, в то время как display занимает всю доступную ему ширину.

Подробнее на [HTMLBook](http://htmlbook.ru/css/display)